# Unable to setup callback URL for facebook workplace webhook

Tags: php, facebook, webhooks, facebook-workplace

I am trying to build a chatbot for facebook workplace but I have got stuck while creating the webhook for the chatbot.

After entering the Callback URL and verify_token, its showing me the error as:
**Problem Setting Up Webhook Subscription
We could not verify the webhook callback. Make sure your webserver is listening and reachable through the specified callback url.**

The Callback URL is HTTPS secured one. Following is the code I have placed in the php file:

```
$verify_token = "token";
$hub_verify_token = null;

if(isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {
    $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    $hub_verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
}

if ($hub_verify_token === $verify_token) {
    echo $challenge;
}
```

The callback URL is getting called from the browser as well.

Comment: _“The callback URL is getting called from the browser as well.”_ - that doesn’t say anything about whether Facebook can reach it or not. Is your SSL certificate valid? It won’t work with self-signed ones, or if your server provides an incomplete certificate chain. What does https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, can it at least connect to the URL?

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Its showing SSL error.

Comment: Did you actually solve this? I'm trying to locally develop with this using ngrok and I'm getting the same error...

Comment: I too am using ngrok to expose my localhost, but it is giving this error